# Update existing design of a website, use of CSS

Tags: css

I'd like to get opinions if this plan is worthwhile or not.
I have an existing site, and some elements have a CSS class defined.
I thought I would append each element that has a class with a new class:

```
<div class="existingClass">
```

would turn into:

```
<div class="existingClass newClass">
```

Then, if I want to override any attributes in "existingClass", I would do so in "newClass" (because the last class attributes are taken?).
I figure this way, nothing would break, so I do not risk anything because I am not removing "existingClass".

Any problems with this plan?

Comment: Why don't you make a backup somewhere and start changing the CSS there? And overwrite the other CSS file when you are done.

Comment: But the result wouldn't be kind of messy? From now on, you would have to carry both the base css and this patch css.

Comment: "nothing would break" - wrong. "override"- right.

Answer (score 0):

First know what is in the **existingClass**. Write **newClass** in such a manner that it won't break the layout. For knowing what is in the **existingClass** use tools like firebug to save time.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed this seems to be a good approach, if you don't want to mess editing the already written CSS.

What you must master are *CSS precedence rules*, also known as CSS specificity.

Some good articles about it:

- [Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).
- [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

This is important because when you want to change a style, that chance will be visible only if you follow appropriately those guidelines. If you don't, then you'll face some troubles when rendering your page.